# repair the static route to allow traffic to right place

Tags: networking, routing, vpn

I recently was taking an online test and I got the below question.

The server has been configured with a TUN device `tun-aib0` that acts as an endpoint for a VPN tunnel.  The IP address of the device is **192.xxx.xx.xx** and the network it is on is using a 22 bit netmask (**255.255.252.0**).

The problem is that the server needs to be able to communicate with the **10.xx.xxx.x** network with a 24 bit netmask (**255.255.255.0**) but none of the traffic appears to be reaching the other VPN endpoint and instead is trying to be sent out to the public internet over `eth0`.

Please repair the static route for **10.xx.xxx.0** so that traffic goes to the right place.

I read the topics on subnet and kernel virtualization. I have a basic understanding on setting up of network. I am trying to figure out how should I approach the above problem. I believe it has to do something with `/etc/sysconfig/network` and setting up a bridge for eth0 in that file. However, I am not sure if am correct.

Comment: Did you try setting route for `10.xx.xxx.0` go through VPN connection?

Comment: @Gnouc, I was not clear with the question. I did not do it. I am now trying to figure out how this route works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question (as I understand it) is to set a static route over the VPN device for the net `10.xx.xx.xx/24`.
Now the traffic is going over the default route to `eth0`.

So first remove the `10.xx.xx.xx` route if available:

```
root@host:~# route del -net 10.xx.xx.0/24
```

Then set the correct route:

```
root@host:~# route add -net 10.xx.xx.0/24 dev tun-aib0
```

In the end the routing table should probably look like this:

```
root@host:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway             Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.xx.xx.xx    <ip-vpn-gateway>    255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun-aib0
yy.yy.yy.yy     0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.xx.xx.0      0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun-aib0
0.0.0.0         <ip-local-router>   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Where `yy.yy.yy.yy` is your local net.

Comment: thanks for the info. So if I understand it correctly, I have `eth0` which is open to the public internet. Now, I have to configure the VPN in between the server and public internet. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, the vpn itself is already connected, but the route to the net 10.xx.xx.0 is not set correctly in the question. You have to manually set the route with the command in my answer. After that all packages to a `10.xx.xx.xx` ip address will be routed through the `tun-aib0` interface.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the route is initially configured in a way as `server -> tun-aib0 -> eth0 -> public internet`. However, according to the question, it should be configured as `server -> tun-aib0 -> 10.xx.xxx.0`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You cannot say, the route of the server. As you see there are 4 different routes. Those routes are all for different destinations. For example in the final routing table of my answer: if a package is sent to 10.xx.xx.25 it will be sent over the inferface `tun-aib0`, `tun-aib0` goes over the <ip-vpn-gateway> and this ip is a internet ip. Lets assume it's `1.1.1.1`. So for this ip, there is no specific route. So the default route (with dest. `0.0.0.0`) will be taken. And this route points over the local-router to the internet. And from the router to the next hop and so on.

Comment: Initially the route was (i assume) set wrong. The route `10.xx.xx.0` was not set or pointed to the wrong interface/gateway.